# Nodejs sessions not persisting in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I can't for the life of me work out why my sessions or cookies aren't persisting across url's

**express**

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'somethign secrect',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        domain: config.cookieDomain,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        maxAge: null,
        cookie: { domain:config.cookieDomain}
    },
    rolling: true
}));
```

**url /auth**

```
                //Store cookies for 1 hour
                console.info(options.req.session); //output 1
                options.req.session.HUTBER = 'JAMIE'; 
                console.info(options.req.session); //output 2
```

**url /auth/callback **

```
    console.info('auth', req.session); //output 3
```

**terminal output**

```
//Output 1
@40000000576c2d6d061dbe14 Session {
@40000000576c2d6d061dc1fc   cookie: 
@40000000576c2d6d061dc1fc    { path: '/',
@40000000576c2d6d061dc1fc      _expires: null,
@40000000576c2d6d061dc5e4      originalMaxAge: null,
@40000000576c2d6d061dc5e4      httpOnly: true,
@40000000576c2d6d061dc9cc      domain: 'mysite.co.uk',
@40000000576c2d6d061dc9cc      secure: false,
@40000000576c2d6d061dcdb4      cookie: { domain: 'mysite.co.uk' } } }

//Output 2
@40000000576c2d6d0624e61c Session {
@40000000576c2d6d0624ea04   cookie: 
@40000000576c2d6d0624ea04    { path: '/',
@40000000576c2d6d0624edec      _expires: null,
@40000000576c2d6d0624edec      originalMaxAge: null,
@40000000576c2d6d0624f1d4      httpOnly: true,
@40000000576c2d6d0624f1d4      domain: 'mysite.co.uk',
@40000000576c2d6d0624f5bc      secure: false,
@40000000576c2d6d0624f5bc      cookie: { domain: 'mysite.co.uk' } },
@40000000576c2d6d0624f9a4   HUTBER: 'JAMIE' }

//Output 3
@40000000576c2d7c14dfd57c auth Session {
@40000000576c2d7c14dfdd4c   cookie: 
@40000000576c2d7c14dfdd4c    { path: '/',
@40000000576c2d7c14dfe134      _expires: null,
@40000000576c2d7c14dfe134      originalMaxAge: null,
@40000000576c2d7c14dfe51c      httpOnly: true,
@40000000576c2d7c14dfe51c      domain: 'mysite.co.uk',
@40000000576c2d7c14dfe904      secure: false,
@40000000576c2d7c14dfecec      cookie: { domain: 'mysite.co.uk' } } }
```

How can I get data across the 2 routes?

Answer (score 1):

First you are using the default session store for the session middleware. The default session store store your session information in memory and is suitable only for development and testing purposes. If you are using multiple application instances and a load balancer (what you normally expect on production) then the default session store will not work for you. I recommend you use another store like [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) or something else that save your session information into a specialized store.

Comment: I wondered if it was something to do with the domain not being correct and if this was the correct syntax for setting the domain. I must admit its not actually live just yet, but intergration/beta

Comment: Maybe @jamie-hutber. By default you left the domain setting blank unless you are dealing with a session for multiple sites that are subdomains of the same common domains (a cookie for a.b.com, b.b.com y c.b.com). Additionally if the domain is not set correct then the cookie will not be sent back to the server and it will be impossible to track session.